# How to evaluate $C$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Let B be the unit ball in the plane and let $u$ be a solution of the boundary
>   value problem:
>
> $∆u = C$ in $B$
>
> $\frac{∂u}{∂n} = 1 $ on $ ∂B$
>
> where $∆ $denotes the Laplace operator, ∂B denotes the boundary of $B$ and
>   $\frac{∂u}{∂n}$ denotes the outer normal derivative on the boundary. Evaluate $C$, given
>   that it is a constant.

My attempt : actually  im thinking about  Green's identity

$$\int_\Omega \Delta u \, dx = \int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} \, dS.$$

But here i don't  know  how to  colloborate   this formula with my  given problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close, to wit:

The divergence theorem--AKA Green's identity--states

$\displaystyle \int_B \nabla \cdot \nabla u \; dA = \int_{\partial B} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n} \; dS, \tag 1$

$dA$ and $dS$ being the area and length elements on $B$ and $\partial B$, respectively.  Given that

$ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 1, \tag 2$

we find

$\displaystyle \int_{\partial B} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n} \; dS = \int_{\partial B} 1\; dS = 2\pi(1) = 2\pi; \tag 3$

on the other hand,

$\displaystyle \int_B \nabla \cdot \nabla u \; dA = \int_B \nabla^2 u \; dA = \int_B C \; dA = C \pi (1)^2 = C \pi; \tag 4$

equating these two yields

$C \pi = 2\pi, \tag 5$

that is,

$C = 2. \tag 6$

Comment: thanks u  @Robert lewis  sir

Comment: @jasmine:. you are more than welcome, my friend.  And thanks for the "acceptance".  Cheers!